# Pattern recognition in multiple time series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, pattern-recognition

I'm trying to detect two types of patterns in sets of 10 time series. The two patterns occur quite close together, and the first is usually higher frequency than the second one. Here's an example:

[image: Sample time series]

The red and green dashed lines mark roughly where the two patterns start in each time series. Across the 10 time series, the start times of each pattern also form a roughly hyperbolic shape. But as can be seen in this example, sometimes one of the two patterns is missing, and sometimes the whole time series is bad (e.g. first and third plots from the bottom). I'd like to infer the locations of the red and green lines in all ten time series. Is there an algorithm that can do this despite the patterns being missing from some of the time series? I do have a training set, so this could be a supervised learning problem.